# How to set CustomView size?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am creating a triangle (Custom View) and then adding it to the parent view (RelativeLayout). i am facing problem here was view taking full screen of parent, how can i set the size of custom view upto that boundaries. triangle extends from view and it has touch listeners. dynamically i'm changing the size of the triangle.

i was added onMeasure() to that view but it takes some fixed amount of width and height..

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Width spec: " + MeasureSpec.toString(widthMeasureSpec));
    Log.d(TAG, "Height spec: " + MeasureSpec.toString(heightMeasureSpec));

    int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

    int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    int chosenWidth = chooseDimension(widthMode, widthSize);
    int chosenHeight = chooseDimension(heightMode, heightSize);

    int chosenDimension = Math.min(chosenWidth, chosenHeight);

    setMeasuredDimension(chosenDimension, chosenDimension);
}
```

i want set the width and height of custom view depending on the size of view when user change how much it has. look at the image.

[image]

Comment: i was edited my question with image.

Comment: What is the width and height do you want the custom view to be? The views will always be a rectangular shape even though you draw a triangle inside it.

Comment: ok how can i create a rectangle for my view depends on the height and width of triangle. and i want to clip that triangle from that view.

Comment: You can have a triangle that paints only inside the triangle and not draw anything outside it. I.e do not set a background Colour to the custom view.

Comment: those triangle points are default at first, points should be change dynamically depends on the user requirements, he can change where ever he wants...

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter where the points are. You can draw the triangle of any orientation. But the custom view will always be a rectangular.  If you do not draw anything outside the triangle the view will appear triangular.

Comment: i'm able to draw the triangle depends on points, but i want to set the width and height of the view.should be upto triangle boundaries....

Comment: From those three points find the max x position. Find the max y position of the points. Then use those max x and maxy to set the measured width and height of the custom view.

Comment: if i create like this, even if i touch on the outside of the triangle i.e in side of rectangle, touch events will trigger. in that time i it will be mismatch..

Comment: For that you need to figure out if the touch happened inside or outside the triangle and ignore those are outside in onTouchEvent method.

Comment: already i did that. if i have more view's at nearer to each other. this time difficult to find on which view i touched..